# Expressing a number that doesn't exist

Tags: notation, prime-numbers

How can one express something like $x \in \pi$ where $\pi$ is a set of prime numbers and $d$ is some divisor such that $\pi = \lbrace n:d|n\rbrace = \lbrace {1, p}\rbrace$? Or should I do something like this $\pi = \lbrace p:d|p=\lbrace1, p\rbrace\rbrace$? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you write out in word what you want your set to be? It's not entirely clear right now.

Comment: @Johanna Fixed.

Comment: No, not fixed: what is this `d`, coming out from nowhere?

Comment: I don't get what is so unclear about this. Can you please explain? @Did d is just some divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to express the fact that $\pi$ is the set of prime numbers.  One is just
$$
\pi = \{p\in\mathbb{N} : p\text{ is prime}\}.
$$
More explicitly, you could write
$$
\pi = \{p\in\mathbb{N} : \forall_{d\in\mathbb{N}}(d\mid p\rightarrow d = 1\vee d=p)\}
$$
or
$$
\pi = \{p\in\mathbb{N} : \neg\exists_{d\in\mathbb{N}-\{1,p\}} (d\mid p) \}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would just express it as $\{ p \in \mathbb{N} | p\text{ is prime} \}$. Every positive integer larger than $1$ has at least two divisors: $1$ and itself, so your alternatives are false. If you really want to express it in terms of divisors, you could write: $\{ p \in \mathbb{N} | p \text{ has exactly two distinct divisors} \}$.

Comment: Maybe then like this: $\lbrace p \in \mathbb N | \lbrace n: n|p\rbrace = \lbrace 1, p\rbrace\rbrace$?

Comment: @SalmonKiller That looks correct to me :)

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction. :)

Comment: That seems confusing to me; it also includes the possibility that $p=1$, which I'm not sure you want.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently one of the correct ways is this: $$\lbrace p\in \mathbb N : p \in\lbrace n:n|p\rbrace = \lbrace 1,p\rbrace\rbrace$$.